# SSR or Opto-Coupler relay only works if shorted

Tags: pi-zero-w, pigpio, relay

I have a SSR 4 channel relay and an Opto-Coupler one channel relay. Both where specified to work on 3.3V signals. I wrote a quick test program on my raspberrypi zero w and tried both relays with my 12V power supply and a pump/motor.
Now the weird part. Both relays turn on and off their control leds, indicating that the relay should close or open - but none of them do. The pump/motor only spins if the control led is on and I short the load end with my pliers.

I read a lot about the relays. And double checked all my settings. But nothing helps and I don't have any more ideas.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here's my schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiCX2b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These are the components I bought:

- [Opto coupler](https://www.ebay.de/itm/252993630298?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20170511121231%26meid%3D7ec4510caa7f417d90217770c0e8a775%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D15%26sd%3D252993630298%26itm%3D252993630298%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057%26brand%3DMarkenlos&_trksid=p2380057.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3Abfa7e53f-d275-11eb-96e0-8aa737602ed7%7Cparentrq%3A2df81e5117a0a4d75f9751ddfff7a8e2%7Ciid%3A1)
- [4 channel SSR](https://www.ebay.de/itm/253093672937?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20170511121231%26meid%3D7ec4510caa7f417d90217770c0e8a775%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D15%26sd%3D252993630298%26itm%3D253093672937%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057%26brand%3DOmron&_trksid=p2380057.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3Abfa7e53f-d275-11eb-96e0-8aa737602ed7%7Cparentrq%3A2df81e5117a0a4d75f9751ddfff7a8e2%7Ciid%3A1)

I did the shorting test with the opto coupler between NO and COM and on the SSR module between A and B.
In case of the opto coupler the motor stays on while shorting the circuit and turns off if I remove the pliers. I suggest this module is broken and I ordered a new one to confirm this.

While the SSR module, I think, needs a little kick with the pliers. It than stays on and turns off when the control signal switches off. But won't turn on again when the control signal comes back. Until I shorten the A,B contacts again.

I tried a level up circuit for my rpis control signal, too. To pull it up to a 5V signal. In this case booth modules control leds keep on all the time. No matter what signal is applied to the pin.
So I assume they do work correctly with the lower 3.3V signal from the rpi as aspected.

This is the level up curcuit I used.

[image: This is the level up curcuit I used.]

Comment: you are asking a technical question about an unknown SSR module switching the output of an unknown power supply into an unknown load

Comment: the title of your post makes no sense ... how can you say that the SSR is working when you are removing it from the circuit by shorting the output pins?

Comment: Ah, your "***But none off them does***" comment is not very clear. If your problem is "***Relay always on, never off***", then let me know and I can try to give more comments.

Comment: A [schematic](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question/2075?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.3165#2075) is much better than "word salad"

Comment: I'm using the standard circuit like this one: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=176479
The SSR Module is this: https://www.komputer.de/zen/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=390&zenid=qmg82gnr36gbe7jnar8skrla73
And the Opto Coupler is this: https://www.ebay.de/itm/273947719617?chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkcid=28&var=573870826719
I'm able to say that the input side of the relays are working because of thier build in control lights. 
The power supply is a 12V/ 5A DC wall mounted brick like everybody on earth is using. ;)